# Linq to xml update via xelement

Tags: asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an xml document and i would like to use linq to xml to update totalGrade to values i have in a list. any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EmpFinanceList>
  <EmployeeFinance>
    <EmpEmployId>122</EmpEmployId>
    <EmpPersonalId>23000</EmpPersonalId>
    <dateofApp>2011-10-31T00:00:00</dateofApp>
    <dateofEmpl>2013-02-15T00:00:00</dateofEmpl>
    <dateofTerm />
    <grade_id>73</grade_id>
    <position_id>2065</position_id>
    <startDate>2013-02-14T00:00:00</startDate>
    <endDate>2013-02-21T00:00:00</endDate>
    <Exchange_rate>200</Exchange_rate>
    <housing>45000</housing>
    <base_pay>150000</base_pay>
    <totalGrade>0</totalGrade>
    <toalPosition>0</toalPosition>
  </EmployeeFinance>
```

EDITED -------------

this is how i created my xml file, please tell me if im wrong and what to do

```
   private static void getEmployeeForEmpFinance(List<BasicPay> EmployeeEmployList)
        {
            var employeeFinance = new List<BasicPay>();
            var context = new SSPModel.sspEntities();
            for (int i = 0; i < EmployeeEmployList.Count; i++)
            {
                    int empID = EmployeeEmployList.ElementAt(i).employee_personal_id;
                    //var dateOfTermination = EmployeeEmployList.ElementAt(i).dateofTerm;
                    // Debug.WriteLine(dateOfTermination);
                    var query = from c in context.Employee_Financial
                                where c.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id == empID 
                                //orderby c.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id ascending
                                select new BasicPay
                                {
                                  base_pay=  c.Base_Pay,
                                  housing=  c.Housing_Allowance,
                                  Base_pay_currency = c.Base_Pay_Currency
                                };
                    var empfinance = query.ToList();
                    foreach (var x in empfinance)
                    {
                        EmployeeEmployList.ElementAt(i).housing = x.housing;
                        EmployeeEmployList.ElementAt(i).base_pay = x.base_pay;
                    }                                    
            }

           try
            {
                            var xEle = new XElement("EmpFinanceList",
                            from emp in EmployeeEmployList
                            select new XElement("EmployeeFinance",
                                         new XElement("EmpEmployId", emp.emp_employID),
                                           new XElement("EmpPersonalId", emp.employee_personal_id),
                                           new XElement("dateofApp", emp.dateofApp),
                                           new XElement("dateofEmpl", emp.dateofEmpl),
                                           new XElement("dateofTerm", emp.dateofTerm),
                                           new XElement("grade_id", emp.grade_id),
                                           new XElement("position_id", emp.position_id),
                                           new XElement("startDate", emp.startDate),
                                           new XElement("endDate", emp.endDate),
                                           new XElement("Exchange_rate", emp.Exchange_rate),
                                           new XElement("housing", emp.housing),
                                           new XElement("base_pay", emp.base_pay),
                                           new XElement("totalGrade", 0),
                                           new XElement("toalPosition",0)
                                       ));
                string path1 = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString();
                string un = "\\"+GlobalClass.GlobalVar + "empFinance.xml";
                GlobalClass.GlobalUrl = path1 + un;
                xEle.Save(GlobalClass.GlobalUrl);
                Debug.WriteLine("Converted to XML " + GlobalClass.GlobalUrl);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
           getFromAllBenGrade();
           //getFromAllBenGrade(EmployeeEmployList);
        }
       public static void getFromAllBenGrade()
        {
            var totalGrade = new List<BasicPay>();
            var context = new SSPModel.sspEntities();
            XElement xelement = XElement.Load(GlobalClass.GlobalUrl);

            var query = from nm in xelement.Elements("EmployeeFinance")
                        select new BasicPay
                        {
                            employee_personal_id = (int)nm.Element("EmpPersonalId"),
                            grade_id = (int)nm.Element("grade_id"),
                            totalGrade = (int)nm.Element("totalGrade")
                        };
            var x = query.ToList();

            Debug.WriteLine("Taken from xml:");
            foreach (var xEle in x)
            {
                var query1 = from ee in context.Employee_Employ
                             join abg in context.All_Inc_Ben_Grade
                             on ee.Grade_Id equals abg.GradeID
                             join abl in context.All_Inc_Ben_Listing
                             on abg.All_Inc_Ben_ListingID equals abl.ID
                             where ee.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id == xEle.employee_personal_id && abl.Part_of_basic == "Y" && abl.Status == "A"
                             select new BasicPay
                             {
                                 all_ben_listID = abl.ID,
                                 amount = abl.Amount

                             };
                var y = query1.ToList();
                int? calculation;
                int? total = 0;
                foreach (var xyz in y)
                {
                    calculation = xyz.amount;
                    total = total + calculation;

                }
                xEle.totalGrade = total;
               // totalGrade.Add(xEle);

                //var doc = XDocument.Load(GlobalClass.GlobalUrl);
                //var hhhh = doc.Root.Element("EmployeeFinance")
                //                    .SetElementValue("totalGrade", total);

            }


            for (int i = 0; i < totalGrade.Count(); i++)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(totalGrade.ElementAt(i).employee_personal_id);
                xelement.Elements("EmployeeFinance").Where(d => int.Parse(d.Attribute("EmpPersonalId").Value) == totalGrade.ElementAt(i).employee_personal_id).SingleOrDefault().SetAttributeValue("totalGrade", totalGrade.ElementAt(i).totalGrade);
            }

        }
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < totalGrade.Count(); i++)
            {
                xelement.Descendants("EmployeeFinance").Where(d => int.Parse(d.Attribute("EmpPersonalId").Value) == totalGrade.ElementAt(i).employee_personal_id).Single().SetAttributeValue("totalGrade", totalGrade.ElementAt(i).totalGrade);
            }

Comment: please update this in your question mate!!

Comment: i added my two classes .. i my get down arrowed cos i posted this already but oh well.. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
        var result = from element in doc.Descendants("EmployeeFinance")
                     select element;
        foreach (var ele in result)
        {  
            ele.SetElementValue("totalGrade", newvalue);

        }
        doc.Save(path);
```

1. Load the Document
2. Select result
3. Loop through each xml block (in case you have multiple record)
4. Set the new value
5. Save the xml document

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to load that document:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
```

After that, you'll be able to change `<totalGrade>` element value:

```
doc.Root.Element("EmployeeFinance")
        .SetElementValue("totalGrade", newValue);
```

**UPDATE**

If you're trying to set that value while xml is generated change that line:

```
                               new XElement("totalGrade", 0),
```

changing `0` to you list item property/field:

```
                               new XElement("totalGrade", emp.totalGrade),
```

Comment: Error 1 Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local